# Ingresar números por teclado hasta ingresar cadena vacía. invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Tags: python

Si quiero ingresar números por teclado hasta que oprima <kbd>Enter</kbd> como en el ejemplo:

```
num = int(input("num:"))
while (num!=""):
    num = int(input("num:")).
    nro = int(input("Ingrese un numero: "))
```

y me da este error como lo puedo solucionar:

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: Los `while` no llevan paréntesis. Estas comparando un entero con una cadena.

Answer (score 4):

El problema es que cuando pulsas <kbd>Enter</kbd> sin ingresar un número para terminar, `input` retorna una cadena vacía (`''`). Al intentar hacer el casting a `int` de la misma tienes el error mencionado:

> Error de valor: literal inválido para entero de base 10: ''

porque obviamente una cadena vacía no representa ningún entero.

Si usas Python >= 3.8 es un buen ejemplo para utilizar las [expresiones de asignación (operador "walrus")](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions):

```
while entrada:= input("num: "):
    num = int(entrada)
    # hacer algo con num
```

`while entrada:= input("num: "):` lo que hace es en cada iteración del `while` asignar a la variable `num` la entrada del usuario. Luego se evalúa si `num` es o no verdadero. En Python una cadena vacía es evaluada como falso y una cadena con cualquier contenido es evaluada como verdadero, por lo que si ingresas una cadena vacía `num` se evalúa como falso y `while` termina.

Si quieres puedes usar un bloque `try-except` para validar que el usuario ingrese un entero válido (si no ingresa una cadena vacía, sino algo que no es convertible a entero):

```
while entrada:= input("num: "):
    try:
        num = int(entrada)
    except ValueError:
        print("No ha ingresado un entero. Intentelo de nuevo")
    else:
        # hacer algo con num
        pass
```

Esto evitará que se produzca una excepción si se ingresa algo que no sea un entero o que la petición de nuevos enteros termine en tal caso, solo dejará de pedir enteros si se ingresa una cadena vacía.

Si no quieres o puedes usar el operador walrus, puedes hacer algo como:

```
while True:
    entrada = input("num: ")
    if not entrada:
        break
    try:
        num = int(entrada)
    except ValueError:
        print("No ha ingresado un entero. Intentelo de nuevo")
    else:
        # hacer algo con num
        pass
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo único que hace falta es un buen manejo de excepciones para lo que quieres lograr. Creo que este código soluciona lo tu problema

```
num = 0
while num!="":
    try:
        print("Ingrese un número")
        num = int(input("num:"))
    except:
        print("Por favor ingresa un número valido")
```

Comment: Considera leer [answer], si editas y nos explicas ese manejo de excepciones ayudaría mucho

Comment: Hola Ricardo, ten en cuenta que tu código genera un ciclo infinito. `num` jamás va a ser una cadena vacía (siempre es un entero, gracias a `num = int(input("num:"))` por lo que `num!=""` siempre será cierta y nunca se saldrá del ciclo.

Comment: Gracias @FJSevilla.  Pues de lo que entendí que requería era justamente eso, que siempre entrara en un bucle a menos que no introdujera número. Si lo corres en en Spyder funciona perfectamente, sin embargo mucho más completa y detallada tu respuesta amigo

Comment: Leeré lo recomendado @Aprendiz

Answer (score 0):

Una forma alternativa, para complementar lo que ya han dicho, pero sin usar captura de errores:
El `if` evalúa si la cadena de entrada está compuesta de números.
El `elif` evalúa si la entrada tiene datos (pero que no son números)
El `else` por default le toca la condición restante: cadena vacia.

```
user_in = "0"
while user_in != "":
    user_in = input("Ingrese un numero: ")
    if user_in.isdigit():
        print("El dato es un entero")
    elif len(user_in) > 0:
        print("El dato NO es un entero")
    else:
        print("Fin del bucle")
```